# Why can you use eval() with the function repr(y) inside and not str(y)?

Tags: python, string, eval, repr

Here is some code that I've found and would like for someone to explain.

If I assign a string to the variable y, evaluate it with the eval function and assign the content to the variable y2, the interpreter returns true.

```
>>> y = 'a string'
>>> y2 = eval(repr(y))
>>> y == y2
>>> True
```

Where as using str(y) in this fashion:

```
>>> eval(str(y))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1
a string
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

is not allowed. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str()` just returns the string itself, it doesn't put quotes around it like `repr()` does.

```
y2 = eval(repr(y))
```

is equivalent to:

```
y2 = 'a string'
```

Since `repr()` adds quotes, this is valid.

```
y2 = eval(str(y))
```

is equivalent to:

```
y2 = a string
```

which is obviously nonsense because there are no quotes.

Comment: @Luis see the docs for [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) specfically the part that says: *For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval()* and compare that to [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) which says: *[...]The difference with repr(object) is that str(object) does not always attempt to return a string that is acceptable to eval(); its goal is to return a printable string[...] ''.*