# How to remove single quotes output?

Tags: python

I have a code, which takes a string from `input_file_1` and two numbers to slice the string from `input_file_2`, the output strings are written in `output_file` and divided by space:

```
def task_3(input_file_1, input_file_2, output_file):
    with open(input_file_1) as i_f_1, open(input_file_2) as i_f_2, open(output_file, 'w') as o_f:
        result = []
        for line_1, line_2 in zip(i_f_1.readlines(), i_f_2.readlines()):
            start, finish = line_2.split()
            result.append(line_1[int(start):int(finish)+1])
        o_f.write(' '.join(repr(i) for i in result))

task_3('test_import_file_2_1.txt', 'test_import_file_2_2.txt', 'output_file.txt')
```

The problem is that output looks like this:

> 'tPGRIXNp' 'JEflNBYRbuLkOiZqQHYNNTWPUIPNibcIpSL'
> 'yDvBXxyOUwjGAemSbsuHupMmGIWpTwv'...

Whereas it must look like this:

> tPGRIXNp JEflNBYRbuLkOiZqQHYNNTWPUIPNibcIpSL
> yDvBXxyOUwjGAemSbsuHupMmGIWpTwv...

As you can see strings are attached to single quotes, which I can't get rid off.

Comment: Does this solves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string BTW I think you don't need to use `repr` as your list only has string, and in any case you should be using `str` instead of `repr`.

Comment: No, I already used `join` method. I need to remove quotes somehow.

UPD. I have removed `repr` without using `str` and everything is alright. No quotes. Thank you. Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python write string to a file without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857300/python-write-string-to-a-file-without-quotes)

Comment: On a side note, [if you're curious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30315372/16757174) about why `repr()` adds quotes: from the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) for `repr()`: "this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing function "repr"

```
o_f.write(' '.join(i for i in result))
```

Also you can provide an example of your input files to reproduce the problem on my computer.

Comment: Thank you, that was a problem. Any thoughts why `repr` caused the issue?

Comment: The repr() function returns a printable representation of the given object.
If you give to repr an string as parameter `repr()` adds the `' '`
You can try this:
`print(repr('hello'))`
`print('hello')`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `repr` and you'll get what you want.
The reason: `repr("string") = "'string'"`. So it adds a pair of single quotes to every line of your output.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the builtin that you must use to convert a value to string in Python is `str`, not `repr`.

`str` and `repr` call the methods `__str__` and `__repr__` of the object. You can [check in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr) how they work and that are the use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove "'", you can just use

```
String_name.replace("'","")
```